# Simple cron job in google app engine (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron, scheduled-tasks

I need help in implementing a simple cron job in GAE (python).

According to what I understood from appengine documentation, I made a file cron.yaml in the application root directory with the following content:

```
cron:
- description: blah blah
  url: /crontask
  schedule: every 1 minute
```

And my app.yaml file has the following content:

```
application: template-123
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: template-123.app
```

I made all my application code (cron and other parts) into a single file "template-123.py". In the code I implement cron in the following way:

```
class CronTask(Handler):

    def  post(self):
        i=25
        number = Birthday(day = i)
        number.put()
```

And I tell the code to use this class for cron by stating: ('/crontask', CronTask).

However no new entries are uploaded to the datastore (as I believe they should be). And I know that it isn't a problem with the way I'm accessing the data store because when I try to do the same thing manually (upload entries to the data store in my non-cron part of application) it returns with appropriate results.

So I need some guidance as to what might I be doing wrong or missing? Do have to make some more changes to the yaml files or add some other libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually python files end in py.  the handler should say

```
script: template-123.py
```

Test your cron job locally first.  You should be able to access localhost:8000/_ah/admin, and click on the Cron Jobs link on the left.  It should list all your cron jobs, and you should be able to test them with a link on the page.  Debug on dev_appserver first.

Comment: He uses an example from python27 runtime. Your answer works for python 2.5. You should clarify it, especially when replying to users that just getting started with App Engine.

Comment: Ok so i did what you said and apparently there was an issue with the way i had written "schedule" in cron.yaml file.
Instead of "every 1 minute" it should have been "every 1 minutes".
The code is working fine now, thanks for the help! (:

Comment: oops, I missed that.  Hard to catch.  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 8):

Cron uses GET, not POST. Change your `def post(self)` to `def get(self)` (or whatever else is appropriate).